# Привязка видимости к логической переменной

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Код.

```
// Флажок в коде
bool IsOpened { get; set; }
```

Разметка.

```
<!-- Кнопка в разметке -->
<Button>Открыть</Button>
```

Нужно, чтобы кнопка показывалась только тогда, когда флажок выставлен в false. Как это делается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WPF есть преобразователи типов. [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) используется для преобразования логического в видимость примерно так:

```
<Button Visibility="{
    Binding IsOpened, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}
}" />
```

Если нужно инвертировать логическое значению, потребуются дополнительные усилия на написание собственного преобразователя на основе [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).